# Passing data dynamically to Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have the following HighChart code. I would like to make the data & categories available through an object rather than hard coding it, so that at a later point I can dynamically get the data and assign to the object. Please let me know the necessary changes that needs to be made for this purpose. Thanks in advance.

```
$('#stackedChartContainer').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['IAS', 'Funding', 'Gilts', 'BuyOut']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Millions'
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -100,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 20,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Pensioners',
                    data: [800000000, 904080340, 961576651, 998929115]
                }, {
                    name: 'Deferreds',
                    data: [700000000, 925466733, 1063478804, 1158224555]
                }, {
                    name: 'Active',
                    data: [200000000, 265524863, 305739877, 333386521]
                }]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addSeries / addPoint / setData functions which allows to modify data / series. Categories can be modified by setCategories() function. All of them are documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

In case when you would like to dynamically get data i.e from server/database etc, you can use ajax calling.

Example of it are avaiable here: http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing